# php upload image and display with database (error)

Tags: php

i am trying to upload a image and display it with an databse 
i managed to make it upload and connect to the datbase, but it does not display it
can somebody take a look at my codes at tell me what i am doing wrong:

the db.php:

```
    <?php   
 $host = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $db_name  = "db_php_school";

  mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Database not connect");
 mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("could not connect databse");
 error_reporting("E_ERROR_WORKING");
 echo "Database connecet success";


?>
```

this is the index.php:

```
<?php 


include './classes/image_class.php';

$obj_image = new Image();

if(@$_POST['Submit'])
{
 $obj_image->image_name=str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['txt_image_name']);
 $obj_image->image=str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['txt_image']);

  $obj_image->Insert_into_image();

  $data_image=$obj_image->get_all_image_list();
 $row=mysql_num_rows($data_image);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>NOvaeye </title>
</head>
<body>
 <CENTER><H1>Novaeyewear</H1></CENTER>
 <CENTER><H2>Sunglass</H2></CENTER>

  <CENTER>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table border="1" width="80%">
    <tr>
     <th width="50%">Image NAme</th>
     <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="txt_image_name"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th width="50%">Upload IMage</th>
     <td width="50%"><input type="file" name="txt_image"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td width="50%"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></input></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </CENTER>

  <?php 
  if($row!=0)
  {
  ?>
  <center>
   <table width="80%" border="1"> 
   <?php
    $icount = 1;
    while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($data_image))
    {
     ?>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center" style="width:10%;"><?php echo $icount; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center" style="width:20%;"><?php echo $data['image_name']?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center" style="width:50%;><img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px"></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
     $icount++;
     }
     ?>
   </table>
  </center>
  <?php
 }

  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the image_class.php

```
<?php
 include 'db/db.php' ;

  class Image{

   var 
   $image_id,
   $image_name,
   $image;

  function Insert_into_image(){
   if(isset($_FILES['txt_image']))
   {
        $tempname = $_FILES['txt_image']['tmp_name'];
        $originalname =$_FILES['txt_image']['name'];
        $size =($_FILES['txt_image']['size']/5242888). "MB<br>";
        $type=$_FILES['txt_image']['type'];
        $image=$_FILES['txt_image']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txt_image']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['txt_image']['name']);
      }


    $query = "Insert into t_image_upload
    (
     image_name,
     image
    )
    values
    (
     '$this->image_name',
     '$image'
    )";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
     echo "Insert success";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "Insert not success";
    }
  }

   function get_all_image_list(){
   $query = "select *from t_image_upload";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   return $result;
  }

}
?>
```

but the problem probably lays down in the index.php on line 63

```
 <td style="text-align:center" style="width:50%;><img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px"></td>
     </tr>
```

here are some screen shots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ8mX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He2OR.png)

Comment: image uploaded successfully?

Comment: <img src="./images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px">  please try this

Comment: Why are all u'r id's 0?? And what do you see when you inspect element? (F12 in chrome)

Comment: yes i do receive them in my database al the time when i upload though the page, and it also downloads the image from the database to the image map, but it does not display the image back to the page, it can probably not find the image in the image map

Comment: @arclite86 did you check with folder?is it in folder?

Comment: aa i problemly already see it when i do inspect element like mitch says i see this text: <td style="text-align:center" image 360graaden(streetview).jpg" width="400px" height="200px"></td> == $0

Comment: aa i problemly already see it when i do inspect element like mitch says i see this text: <td style="text-align:center" image 360graaden(streetview).jpg" width="400px" height="200px"></td> == $0</tr>    but it has to be: image/360graaden(streetview).jpg to display the image it is missing the /

Comment: yes it is in the folder

Comment: @arclite86 
<img src="./images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px">   did you try this?

Comment: In your class Image, $image is the image name, and $this->image_name is null. Correct the little problems before trying to figure the real problem.

Comment: also there is no form action in form

Comment: also don't use mysql_ functions they are depreciated, use mysqli or pdo

Comment: alright i have solved the problem i used: <td>
<"<img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px">
</td>

Comment: alright i have solved the problem i used: <td>
<"<img src="images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px">
</td> so in the inspect ellement it will show <img src="images/theimage> instead of <img scr image "theimage".jpg

but now i would like to upload multiple images i have used  <th width="50%">Upload IMage</th>
     <td width="50%"><input type="file" name="txt_image" multiple></input></td>
    </tr>   but it wil only upload one image at a time

Answer (score 0):

First, check image is uploaded into folder and then try to give absolute path like

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center" style="width:50%;>
<img src="http://localhost/project/images/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="400px" height="200px">
</td>
</tr>
```